# How to get Multiaddr of a peer?

Tags: peers, multiaddress

What is idiomatic way to get peer's [Multiaddr](https://docs.rs/libp2p/latest/libp2p/struct.Multiaddr.html) given we have its [PeerId](https://docs.rs/libp2p/latest/libp2p/struct.PeerId.html)?

There exists [get_authority_ids_by_peer_id](https://docs.rs/sc-authority-discovery/latest/sc_authority_discovery/struct.Service.html#method.get_authority_ids_by_peer_id) which seems useful but when spinning up multiple nodes locally which connect to each other it always returns `None`.

Digging into it, it seems internal `addr_cache` (which holds `PeerId` -> `AuthorityId` -> `Multiaddr` mappings) is only populated when handling `DhtEvent::ValueFound(...)` which are not being emitted in my case.

Some background info on how I run nodes locally:

1. spin up first node with `alice` account
2. spin up 4 more nodes using also predefined accounts by setting 1. as bootnode

Looking at node logs and invoking `system_peers` RPC confirms nodes are connected with each other.

Update:

Seems like `DhtEvent::ValueNotFound(...)` events are being emitted for corresponding Kademlia `get_value` requests that `authority-discovery` worker is creating. So it's probably problem with DHT not having proper entries initially.

Comment: From which peer you want to get the `MultiAddr`? You probably want the `Multiaddr` of some random peer and not only from a validator?

Comment: @bkchr I want `Multiaddr` for any peer in the network that I'm aware of i.e. for peers that are returned in `system_peers` RPC

Answer (score 1):

Given the question in the comment, how to retrieve the addresses of all the peers the node is aware of:

1. This is only giving you information that your node has been learned from other nodes. It doesn't mean that these are all nodes or similar.
2. There is currently no way to access this information. You could "abuse" the the [`network_state`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3ff1afa643a2d1d552f463d923a10c5179267feb/client/network/src/service.rs#L632-L650) function. However, as the docs already tell you, you should not use this function.
3. I still think that you did not explained your issue well enough on what you want to achieve and thus, can not get proper help here. If I'm incorrect, you can open a pr to Substrate to give you this information in a more "stable" way, aka not using `network_state`.

Comment: Let me put it in more simpler terms hopefully explaining it better:

Peers/Nodes are obviously communicating with each other therefore they know each others public ip and ports.

All I'm looking to do is to get that info (ip + port in form of Multiaddr) within node.

For example when spinning up node you can pass '--bootnodes' flag which is Multiaddr containing PeerId. This Multiaddr is stored somehwere - how can I retrieve it in runtime. Obviously I don't want to retrieve Multiaddrs only for bootnodes but for any node I'm connected to.

Comment: Why do you want to have that in the runtime? What are you doing? There is no way currently to have this in the runtime.

Comment: Apologies - 'runtime' was poor term to choose. I mean in the outer node.

"What are you doing?" Creating RPC which for given PeerId (or AuthorityId) will return it's Multiaddrs if node I'm invoking RPC on is connected to peer in question.

Comment: Then you need to do what I described under point 3.