Make peers list persistent
So

what I have: I have a testnet network, I run a full node and connect to a specific bootnode that I specify with arg --bootnodes; after connecting to the bootnode, info about other peers are provided and I am able to connect to them.
what I'd like to have: the possibility to make this peers list persistent, so that if I shutdown my node and then restart I try to reconnect immediately to those peers (this can be useful for example if the bootnode is temporarily unavailable).

Is this possible? Is there a flag/arg for setting this feature?
In case the answer is no and I need to write a custom implementation, how can I get the ip-address&port of a peer I am already connected to? I see there is RPC call system->peers() but it just provides some info (together with peerId) but nothing related to ip-address&port.
In other words I want to figure out two things, first one if there is a built-in mechanism for making the node reconnect to its previous peers after a shutdown&restart, second one if there is a way to get the ipaddress (or dns) and port of the peers my node is currently connected to.

Here is one more pice of your question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8612/how-to-get-multiaddr-of-a-peer?rq=1
